# How to get the length of an attribute within an object with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json object called programs. Within this object i have an array of key/values. I need to get the count of how many of the objects have the key/value of "status": "Review". So here we have 4 objects and two of the have "status": "Review". I need to return this count like this (2)

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "organizationName": "Watertown School",
      "programs": [
          {
              "id": 72,
              "programId": 456456,
              "programName": "name 1",
              "programType": "Phd",
              "applicationType": "Domestic",
              "concentration": "Medicine",
              "formId": 0,
              "isReviewed": true,
              "status": "Review"
          },
          {
              "id": 73,
              "programId": 4564561,
              "programName": "name 2",
              "programType": "Phd",
              "applicationType": "Domestic",
              "concentration": "Medicine",
              "formId": 0,
              "isReviewed": true,
              "status": "Draft"
          },
          {
              "id": 74,
              "programId": 10343431,
              "programName": "name 3",
              "programType": "Phd",
              "applicationType": "Domestic",
              "concentration": "Medicine",
              "formId": 0,
              "isReviewed": true,
              "status": "Review"
          },
          {
              "id": 75,
              "programId": 10031,
              "programName": "namw 4",
              "programType": "Phd",
              "applicationType": "Domestic",
              "concentration": "Medicine",
              "formId": 0,
              "isReviewed": true,
              "status": "Draft"
          },
      ]
}
```

Comment: You can use a simple loop to iterate `programs`.

Comment: data.programs.filter(function (item) {
        return item.status == "Review";
    }).length

link http://jsfiddle.net/4sq2crqv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on where you need this? If it's in the dom you can do something like this:

```
{{ (myObject.programs | filter:{ status: 'Review' }).length }}
```

Here's a jsFiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/2jx5oL78/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to be [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which isn't specific to Angular. For example:

```
// Assuming you had your object as obj
var obj = {}; //Stuff goes here
obj.programs = obj.programs.filter(function (value) {
  if (value.hasOwnProperty('status') && value.status === "Review") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

And from there, you could just call `obj.programs.length`.

The filtered array could be assigned to any variable, just as a note. So, if you only want the count, that would probably be advantageous.

If you're looking to do DOM-based filter, you could use an Angular filter as Mathew Berg suggested, or something along the lines of an `ngIf` or `ngShow` within a repeat, or applying the aforementioned filter directly to the repeat.